# My ASCII art is wrong on a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, ascii-art

I was trying to make an `->` arrow with ASCII art, but my JLabel is not cooperating. It gives it this look instead:

[image: bad ->]

which makes it look like _> or something. How do I fix it?

SSCCE:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame j = new JFrame("TEST");
        j.add(new JLabel(" -> "));
        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        j.pack();
        j.setSize(j.getWidth() * 3, j.getHeight() * 3);
        j.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        j.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the font of your label to whatever font the arrow looks good in.

Comment: Or perhaps use the \u2192 unicode arrow.

Comment: @RussellZahniser: Now that's a good answer. I'd post it as one. Feel free to add an answer copying any text you find helpful from mine and adding that, and I'll remove mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The placement of the `-` relative to the `>` depends on the font. You'll have to find another way to do this, or use a font where the placement is the way you'd like it to be.

Monospaced fonts *tend* to have `-` placed pleasantly next to `>` but it's no guarantee. For instance, right now on SO, `->` looks roughly as mis-aligned as -> does (to me).

A better answer, by [Russell Zahniser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1130930/russell-zahniser) in a comment *(and if he posts it as an answer, I'll delete this one)*, is to use one of the (many) Unicode arrows, such as `\u2192`. There's a useful list [here on the unicode.org site](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_2190.html).

Comment: It's true that `->` looks slightly (!) mis-aligned here, but ... that's not only an issue of the *font*, but also of the *size*. (To put it that way: There simply is no "vertical center" for a character that is 20 pixels high...). Zooming the page (with CTRL+MouseWheel) shows that the alignment of `->` matches for "some" sizes, while for "some" other sizes, it seems to be off by 1 point... (EDIT: And I just noticed that it looks perfectly aligned for me in the **comment**, although it's mis-aligned in the *answer*...)

Comment: I'll switch to @Russel's answer if he posts it, thank you for the monospaced fonts note on height.

Comment: @Marco Interestingly it appears that Chrome scales the font size, so when I zoom I get extremely hi-def fonts, and I can't see any problems.

Comment: @KenzieTogami: Yeah, exactly. Whereas for me (also using Chrome, on Ubuntu) I can clearly see a misalignment. [Unzoomed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FBzVv.png) - [zoomed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UTpqw.png)

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you'll have to use a "Monospaced" font, at least. While this does not *necessarily* mean that the *vertical* alignment of the `-` will match the `>`, it should be so for the standard fonts. In any case, the property of being "monospaced" will make sure that the *width* of all characters will be equal, which is crucial for ASCII art.

```
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame j = new JFrame("TEST");

        JLabel label = new JLabel(" -> ");
        label.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12));

        j.add(label);
        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        j.pack();
        j.setSize(j.getWidth() * 3, j.getHeight() * 3);
        j.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        j.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: A monospaced font is no guarantee of `-` / `>` alignment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sure (inserted this in an edit while you wrote the comment), but the only statement that would have been "universally true" would have been "You have to use a font where these characters match in the desired way". This would not have been helpful for the asker (and I have never seen that in the "Monospspaced"-font, these characters are *not* at least roughly aligned like that - nearly all ASCII art is simply done with the "default" monospaced fonts...)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between

```
->
```

and

> ->

Is the font. If this is ASCII art, you should be using a monospace font(Consolas, Courier New, Monaco...) for your JLabel via `setFont`. something like:

```
JFrame j = new JFrame("TEST");
JLabel label = new JLabel(" -> ");
label.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12)));
j.add(label);
...
```